# Studying once again

Tags: masters, visa

I have tried to pursue an MS course in Computer science, which was a 2 year course. But had to leave the course mid way after 1 year of study. I should mention, the reason was that my academic performance was not up to the mark. But, I was a good student who did my under graduation in Electrical Engineering at the best university in India. I did not really find the course material to be too difficult, I was just a bit aimless at that point of time.

It has been a few months that I have returned back to India. But, I feel like a failure which I need not feel like. I was able to find a 1 year masters course in a related field (in US and also elsewhere). But I want to know if I will face any difficulty in entering US, as far as the visa requirements are concerned.

Comment: Was the 2 year course in the US, thus the worry about applying for a new student visa?

Comment: Did you leave the US on good terms - as in, left in a voluntary way (not deported or otherwise removed), on-time (didn't overstay your visa), and otherwise kept all requirements for the visa?

Comment: I'm no expert, so I'll have to leave it to others to advise, but I don't see any obvious visa-related problem: http://www.alllaw.com/articles/nolo/us-immigration/why-denied-student-visa.html But visas are generally not guaranteed things to begin with, so I (and no one else) can guarantee if you'd get one or not...but I don't see any reason you'd be automatically disqualified for leaving and applying to a different program.

Comment: I would guess that the primary challenge might be to gain admission to a program after having had to leave the other one midway through.  If that proves to be a stumbling block, perhaps you could take some graduate level courses in India to show that you have better focus currently.